# Return a value using Caolan's async module

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I'm wondering if it is possible to make a series of calculations and get the returned value using async.each method. A very simple example of it would be calculating the sum of all elements in an array.

```
function Calculator() {

}

Calculator.prototype.sum = function(elements, callback) {
  var total = 0;
  async.each(elements, function(element, callback) {
    total += element;
    callback();
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    //How can I get total as a returned value of sum?
  });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Summing an array of elements is a synchronous operation. Why are you using `async.each` instead of a normal array loop?

Comment: As I said, it's just a simple example. A more complicated example should be to calculate the total friends of an user in all of his social networks, where you should pass a list of social network and an user name. Each friend count on each social network would be retrieved in an async manner, right? And at the end, I would like to sum up all these friend counts and return it for the next action. I could see another solution is to pass a callback with results as parameter, but it'd be difficult for unit testing, wouldn't it?

Comment: It's not too late to use promises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should be possible: You could use [`async.reduce`](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce). (Although this would required some changes to your code, the current value must be passed through with the callback.

Example from the docs:

```
async.reduce([1,2,3], 0, function(memo, item, callback){
    // pointless async:
    process.nextTick(function(){
        callback(null, memo + item)
    });
}, function(err, result){
    // result is now equal to the last value of memo, which is 6
});
```

Comment: Yeap, but how do you return the result value (which is 6) to the caller function?

Comment: @passkey1510 through a callback. You **cannot** pass it back as a return value of the function. That's not how asynchronous code works!

Comment: Ok thanks a lot @TheHippo. You reconfirmed the point for me :). The only way to deal with the returned value is using a callback!